# CSS text-overflow: ellipsis does not depend on the width

Tags: html, css, truncate, ellipsis

Is it actually possible to use `text-overflow: ellipsis`, when you don't set the width?
Instead of width I need to set it until `100px` from the right. If the text reaches `100px` from the right, it will be hidden and with dots in the front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both margins: left and right to make it work:

```
HTML:
<div class="parent">
    <div class="test">some pseudo-centered text some pseudo-centered text some pseudo-centered text some pseudo-centered text some pseudo-centered text</div>
</div>

CSS:
.test {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 100px;
}
```

A working example online can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/rqb3W/1/

Answer (score 2):

You should just have to add `padding-right: 100px;` to the element with text in.

**HTML**

```
<p>some text</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding-right: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;    
}
```

Here is a **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FuZB9/)** with the above code.

Comment: yeah, but the thing is I need to use text-align: center and it'd not centered anymore if I use padding-right.

Comment: Change the padding to `padding: 0 100px;` ?

Answer (score 0):

`text-overflow: ellipsis` only works if `width` or `max-width` is set in pixels. You can get around this by using `width: calc (69%)` which gets converted to px.

So to answer your question you can try `float:right` with a margin or use `width: calc(100% - 100px);` with `margin-right: 100px`

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow